# Matplotlib x-axis disappear

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm experimenting with python's matplotlib function and having some weird result that the x-axis label disappears from the plot.

I'm trying the following example as shown in this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X60m6GBq4fM):
[image]

In the example, the x-axis is showing the year of the plot.
When I try to do in my own Jupyter notebook, what I get is the following:

Code :

```
yearly_average[-20:].plot(x='year', y='rating', figsize=(15,10), grid=True)
```

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your settings (your code) of the plot?  It's hard for us to pinpoint the error without the code

Comment: It's shown on the screenshot: `yearly_average[-20:].plot(x='year', y='rating', figsize=(15,10), grid=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's convert the Year column in the yearly_average dataframe from a str or object dtype to integer.  Then, plot using pandas plot.

MVCE:

Working example with xaxis ticklabels where dtype 'Year' is integer

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005],'Value':np.random.randint(1000,5000,6)})

df.plot('Year','Value')
```

[image]

Now, let's cast 'Year' as str and test plot again.

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str)
df1.plot('Year','Value')
```

Missing ticklabels

[image]